# Pass the model data into Controller to tabulate/calculate each of the values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a User.cs class model. I would like to get the data in my model and bring it to Controller to do some calculation.

How to pass the model data into Controller to tabulate/calculate each of the values. Example to for loop all the available data and do some calculation.

However, i find that most of the tutorial available are sending Model -> Controller -> View for example.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
        if (User.IsInRole(RoleName))
        {
            var users = _context.Users.ToList();
            var patients = _context.Patients.ToList();
            var patientAllocations = _context.PatientAllocations.ToList();
            var albums = _context.Albums.ToList();

            var viewModel = new ManagePatientsViewModel()
            {
                Users = users,
                Patients = patients,
                PatientAllocations = patientAllocations,
                Albums = albums
            };

            return View(viewModel);
}
```

User Model

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public int userID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you have a model inyour controller, so explain more what's your problem?

Comment: @S.Serp There is no problem, i am asking this question

How to pass the model data into Controller to tabulate/calculate each of the values. Example to for loop all the available data and do some calculation.

Comment: You already have `var users = _context.Users.ToList();` in your GET method to GET the users. Its not clear what you asking. And what 'calculation' do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get model object in controller actions by defining it as a parameter of your action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(ManagePatientsViewModel model)
{
  //you can access model properties...
  for(int i=0; i<model.Users.Count; i++)
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(model.Users[i].email);
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: hi serp, thanks but with your code above. I tried 
for(int x, x < 10; x++) { if(model.email == "xxxx")  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(model.address); } Does not work

Comment: please see updated answer. by the way, i didn't see address in your `User` model. probably it is not shown here or it is some property of other types (eg `Patient` )... You can put a break point inside for-loop and evaluate all properties of the model

Comment: hi serp, yes it works but from your code above. ManagePatientsViewModel is empty we need place the result into ManagePatientViewModel first inorder for the code to work. Thanks as i didn't know the syntax to display each line.